# File Server Resource Manager Expiration Tasks fails with Shadow Copy error

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, volume-shadow-copy

I'm running Windows Server 2012 with File Server Resource Manager role. We have two tasks configured to remove stale files on a X drive. This week I started to see the errors below in Windows Application Logs

> 8235 - File Server Resource Manager failed to initialize the volume scanner.
> 12311 - Shadow copy creation failed for volume 'X:' with error 0x8004532c, A volume shadow copy could not be created or was unexpectedly deleted.

In FSRM console I find the Last Result message: Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004532C

X volume does not have Shadow Copies enabled, but D drive does. Since FSRM documentation and google haven't been of much help, does anyone have a clue on why FSRM is throwing Shadow Copy errors related to a volume that is not Shadow Copy enabled?
How does FSRM uses Shadow Copies for the tasks?

Comment: Please add to your post the output of the command `vssadmin list shadowstorage`.

Comment: Thanks but I'm interested in understanding how FSRM uses Shadow Copies for tasks, not to troubleshoot the shadow copy service

Answer (score 0):

So after some troubleshooting I found that the first step when the task run is to create a snapshot, which I assume uses Shadow Copy service.[image: Expire task initializing]

Looking into the Windows Event Log for FSRM and Shadow Copy errors, I found:

- Application

  - [Source: SRMSVC] - 8235 - File Server Resource Manager failed to initialize the volume scanner
  - [Source: SRMSVC] - 12311 - Shadow copy creation failed for volume 'X:' with error 0x8004231f.  The volume might be configured with inadequate shadow copy storage area.  Storage reports may be temporarily unavailable for this volume.
- System

  - [Source: volsnap] - 39 - When preparing a new volume shadow copy for volume X:, the shadow copy storage on volume D: could not be located in non-critical space.  Consider using a shadow copy storage volume that does not have any shadow copies.

I had already seen error 39 related to a vss writer timing out while scanning a volume. Checking the status of vss writers using `vssadmin list writers` output

> Writer name: 'FSRM Writer'
> Writer Id: {12ce4370-5bb7-4c58-a76a-e5d5097e3674}
> Writer Instance Id: {e337e6ed-be6b-4020-a209-34a3066785a0}
> State: [5] Waiting for completion
> Last error: No error

Restarting the File Service Resource Manager service cleared the status of the writer

> Writer name: 'FSRM Writer'
> Writer Id: {12ce4370-5bb7-4c58-a76a-e5d5097e3674}
> Writer Instance Id: {e337e6ed-be6b-4020-a209-34a3066785a0}
> State: [[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Eucc.png)] Stable
> Last error: No error

After this the task ran without issues, BUT, the writer vss FSRM Writer was left in `[5] Waiting for completion state`, which still needs to be investigated.

Long story short, FSRM uses Shadow Copies to create snapshots in its initialization phase.